# Django Tastypie Override URL with slug

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have the following code:

```
def override_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<slug>[\w\d_.-]+)/$" % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name="api_dispatch_detail"),
    ]
```

Which produces an URL like:

```
/api/v1/nodes/<slug>/
```

Everything is fine except that `self.get_resource_uri(bundle)` returns `/api/v1/nodes/<id>/` and I cannot compare the current URL with the resource URI effectively.

What am I doing wrong?

### Solution: working code

I implemented the proposed solution here:
https://github.com/ninuxorg/nodeshot/blob/refactoring/nodeshot/core/base/resources.py

Any additional feedback for improvement is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could override `get_resource_uri` on your resource to return the correct uri. After all, the correct one is the one with the slug since that is the (first) one captured by your resource.

**Update**

The right way to do this is actually to skip `override_urls` and put this on the Resource's Meta:

```
detail_uri_name = 'slug'
```

**TLDR Background**

I dug a bit deeper and it looks like there's a much better place to implement this. The default implementation of `get_resource_uri` (indirectly) calls `self.detail_uri_kwargs` and then `reverse`.

The default implementation of `detail_uri_kwargs` in `ModelResource` just looks up `self._meta.detail_uri_name` (whose name is not intuitive), and grabs that key off the model.  `detail_uri_name` defaults to `pk`.

If you just provide a different name here, you can skip the override_urls and the get_resource_uri!

Something like this (building on the code linked in comments by the OP):

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.bundle import Bundle

class BaseSlugResource(ModelResource):
    """ Base Model Resource using slug urls """

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        detail_uri_name = 'slug'
```

I'm not sure off the top of my head whether resource `Meta`s are inherited (I'm going to guess they're not), so this may not work as a base class.  Luckily, the one line required is probably fine to paste into each Resource that needs it.

Comment: is override_urls correct then? I thought I was doing something wrong that caused get_resource_uri() to return the old URL.

Comment: No, that's the right way to go--`override_urls` is correct.  Note, though, that as of Tastypie 0.9.12 `override_urls` will be deprecated in favor of `prepend_urls` with the same functionality.

Comment: i tried your suggestion here and it works:
https://github.com/ninuxorg/nodeshot/blob/refactoring/nodeshot/core/base/resources.py

can you see anything wrong with the implementation?

Comment: @nemesisdesign Updated with a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to clean it up with a working example even though the @dokkaebi's answer is marked (and partially) correct. The only missing part is you still have to [prepend url](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#using-non-pk-data-for-your-urls) that will be resolved for listing and such.

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from myapp.models import SomeModel

class BaseSlugResource(ModelResource):
    """ Base Model Resource using slug urls """

    class Meta:
        queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
        detail_uri_name = 'slug'

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r'^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<slug>[\w\.-]+)/$' % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'), name='api_dispatch_detail'),
        ]
```

This will display the correct resource_uri's for listing as well as resource get. However, you'll most likely loose {schema} resource (i.e. /api/posts/schema/) as it's treated as a slug too.